# Correct way to run Unit Tests with different beans

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, tdd

I am curious what is the best setup for the following situation:

I have a test class: MyTests with JUnit4 tests. Each of them I want to run with every type of car I specify, for example:

```
        <bean id="myBean" class="com.stuff.Cars"
                factory-method="Toyota"/>

       <bean id="myBean" class="com.stuff.Cars"
                factory-method="Chevrolet"/>
```

I want all the tests to run using both the Chevrolet and the Toyota; what would be the correct way to do this? The naive way would be to just double all the test classes and use Chevrolet instead of Toyota. I am still very new to spring, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JUnit's Parameterized runner: http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have different types of cars and you want build a generic suite of test that all cars must pass, this is contract testing. This video form Ben Rady explain the concept very well with JUnit 4: http://www.benrady.com/2009/12/contract-tests-in-junit-4.html